# Notation: Pointer to array and array of pointers

Tags: c++

I know that:

```
Foo *array[10]; // array of 10 Foo pointers     

Foo (*array)[10]; // pointer to array of 10 Foos
```

However, I don't really understand the logic behind this notation. That is, why does the first part create an array of pointers why the second creates a pointer to an array?

Of course I can easily remember this notation, but I would like to know the logic behind it.

Comment: Since you've tagged this question C++, would you accept the answer **because C did it that way**? :-)

Comment: Try to remember this notation: `int *(*(*(*b)())[10])();` :) [Reading C declarations.](http://www.ericgiguere.com/articles/reading-c-declarations.html)

Comment: AFAIK, the rationale for the way the declarations in C work is that they wanted them to resemble the usage of what they declare. E.g for `Foo (*array)[10];` dererencing it (`*array`) gives you `Foo[10]`. Here's [some reading](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html) on the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For any type `T`, `T *` denotes a new type, "pointer to `T`".

When `T = Foo[10]`, then `T *` is a pointer to an array of ten `Foo`.

However, the notation `Foo * p[10]` is parsed left-to-right, greedily, as `(Foo *) p [10]`, thus being an array of ten `Foo *`. To get the desired pointer-to-array, you have to group the variable name closer to the asterisk, so `T (*p)`, or `Foo (*p) [10]`.

Comment: I learned to read these expressions in more of a logical right-to-left instead of a left-to-right starting at the identifier.  As in: `Foo * p[10]` will get "p is an array of ten pointers to Foo" and `Foo (*p)[10]` as "p is a pointer (parentheses stops right parsing) to an array of 10 Foos".